# Передача стиля переменной

Tags: javascript

Почему так не присваивается высота

```
     var height_parent = this.parentNode.style.height
     height_parent = '260px';
```

а если сделать так

```
    this.parentNode.style.height = '260px';
```

то все ок

```
function furtherMenu(){
document.getElementById('further').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var height_parent = this.parentNode.style.height
    if(height_parent == '470px'){
            this.parentNode.style.height = '260px';
            this.firstChild.innerHTML='Показать подробную информацию';
        }else{
            this.parentNode.style.height = '470px';
            this.firstChild.innerHTML='Скрыть подробную информацию';
        }
    },false)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что height это свойство. Если вы присвоите переменную B значению переменной A, а потом измените В, то A останется прежним. А когда вы используете this.parentNode.style.height вы меняете свойства объекта

Comment: Используйте

var style_parent = this.parentNode.style;
style_parent.height='260px'

и всё будет работать

Comment: @Camaz то что хотели сказать @Gedweb и @VladD - в JS простые типы передаются по значению остальные по ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнительное разъяснение к правильному ответу [@Gedweb](/users/10995/gedweb): строка

```
var height_parent = this.parentNode.style.height
```

приводит к тому, что переменная `height_parent` получает значение, равное *копии* значения `this.parentNode.style.height`. Ваш код сработал бы, если бы переменная `height_parent` после присваивания *стала бы сама* свойством `height` объекта `this.parentNode.style`, но в javascript (да и в большинстве популярных языков) это не так.

Почему же тогда такой код:

```
var style_parent = this.parentNode.style;
style_parent.height='260px';
```

работает? А вот почему: переменная `style_parent` получает *копию ссылки* на объект `style`. Если вы переприсвоите `style_parent`, первоначальное значение `this.parentNode.style` не поменяется по тем же причинам, что и выше. Но когда вы пишете `style_parent.height='260px'`, переменная `style_parent` ссылается на тот же объект, что и `this.parentNode.style`. Поэтому изменение её свойства влияет и на сам объект. Видите?

Answer (score 0):

Хочу предупредить, что Ваш скрипт не является кроссбраузерным, т.к. **addEventListener** поддерживается IE только с 9-ой версии.

```
var  el = document.getElementById('further');

if ('addEventListener' in el) {

   // выполнится для IE 9 и выше, и для всех остальных браузеров 
    el.addEventListener(
        'click',
        function(){     
            alert(this.parentNode.style.height);
        },
        false
    );
} else if ('attachEvent' in window) {

    // выполнится для IE8 и ниже 
    el.attachEvent(
        'onclick',
        function(e){        
            alert(e.srcElement.parentNode.style.height);
        }
    );
}
```